# Calculating the total of a calculated column using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, itunes

I just learnt XSLT today when I wanted to pretty print the playlist export (xml) from itunes. I finally understood how XSLT pertains to XML and how useful it can be. I picked up the code from 
[iTunes2Html](http://www.greeley.org/~hod/dj/iTunes.html) and customized it for my own purposes. I have created a dynamic column which is the playtime/duration for a song (useful for people/djs who set start and end times!). What I wanted at the end of the display is a sumtotal of all the duration column. I can't figure out how to do that. I've researched on stack overflow and google with no luck so far. The results I have found have been confusing.

So can anybody can help me figure out how to calculate the total of a dynamic/calculated column? see [similar question](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200002/post40910.html)

Here is the relevant part of the XSLT

```
<td> <!-- calculating duration : formattime(end | total - start | 0), is there a simpler way to do it? -->
<xsl:variable name="totduration">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string(number(following-sibling::Start_Time))='NaN'">
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Stop_Time"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="string(number(following-sibling::Stop_Time))='NaN'">
        <xsl:value-of  select="number(following-sibling::Total_Time) - number(following-sibling::Start_Time)"/>
    </xsl:when>          
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of  select="number(following-sibling::Stop_Time) - number(following-sibling::Start_Time)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<!-- for the javascript approach using jquery. didn't work -->
<span class="sumData" style="display:none"> <xsl:value-of select="$totduration"/></span> 
<xsl:call-template name="formatTime">
  <xsl:with-param name="t" select="$totduration"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
```

Edit: Clarifying the logic of the duration calculation. Since start and stop are optional, the actual formula is (stop | total) - (start | 0). This means that if neither exists, then duration is identical to length i.e. it plays from start to end! Every song has that property. However if even one of the nodes (start or stop) is defined then the duration can be different from the total length of the song.

some sample XML

```
  <songlist>
<song>
  <Track_ID>169</Track_ID>
  <Name>AAAAA</Name>
  <Album>AAAAA</Album>
  <Genre>AAAAA</Genre>
  <Start_Time>78000</Start_Time>
  <Stop_Time>122000</Stop_Time>
  <Total_Time>357537</Total_Time>
</song>
<song>
  <Track_ID>174</Track_ID>
  <Name>BBBBBB</Name>
  <Artist>BBBBBB</Artist>
  <Album>BBBBBB</Album>
  <Genre>BBBBBB</Genre>
  <Stop_Time>120000</Stop_Time>
  <Total_Time>275043</Total_Time>
</song>
<song>
  <Track_ID>177</Track_ID>
  <Name>CCCCCC</Name>
  <Artist>CCCCCC</Artist>
  <Album>CCCCCC</Album>
  <Genre>CCCCCC</Genre>
  <Stop_Time>62000</Stop_Time>
  <Total_Time>287738</Total_Time>
</song>
<song>
  <Track_ID>180</Track_ID>
  <Name>DDDDDDD</Name>
  <Artist>DDDDDDD</Artist>
  <Album>DDDDDDD</Album>
  <Genre>DDDDDDD</Genre>
  <Start_Time>43000</Start_Time>
  <Total_Time>400274</Total_Time>
</song>
```

This is the output
[image: Screenshot]

The Desired Output as it would appear at the bottom of the duration column (i.e. sum of all duration):

```
Total Playtime Duration - 9:43
```

Also is there a better way (that what is shown above) to do this formula in xslt? I am currently using `xsl:choose` to check for NaNs and use the alternative accordingly. I can't help but think that there has to be a better way.

```
formattime((stop | total) - (start | 0))
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT2 (which makes this a lot easier) or XSLT1, if you are using XSLt1 do you have the node-set extension available? (or equivalently, which XSLT processor are you using?)

Comment: Why is "length" different than "duration"? Could you, please, explain what is the meaning of "length"? Also, why there isn't any "start time" for two of the tracks? What does this mean? Finally, why the last track doesn't have any "stop time"? Could you, please, provide the *wanted* output?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using IE9 to view the transformations. This is V1 according to <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version='1.0'>

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The start and stop times are optional, and not required! Length is total length of track, duration is only the playtime of the track depending on start & stop times. I will edit the post above to mention the wanted output

Comment: +1 for providing complete, working samples and an explanation that's not lacking important details.

Comment: Vijay
, this doesn't make sense -- if duration is defined based on start and stop time and there are some start/stop times missing, there is no way to calculate the duration. On the other side, in your output, every row has a duration. I find this question lacking logic!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev see my comment to dash1e, they are optional fields, if neither exists, then duration is identical to length i.e. it plays from start to end! Every song has that property. However if even one of the nodes (start or stop) is defined then the duration can be different from the total length of the song. I hope this clarifies the logic.

Comment: @Vijay: It would be best for you to rewrite the question -- and to learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: @Dimitre I think the question was complete, clear and good. The expected result and every bit of information necessary to get to it were given, working code was provided, explanations were there.

Comment: @Tomalak: I disagree with such conclusion: the missing values in the provided output were not explained and it was not explained how in this case some other values were/should-have-been produced. The OP provided clarifying coment only after the second time I asked for this -- just read the comment thread. The question still isn't edited to provide clarifying information about the misleading and confusing output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you exactly what you are looking for:

```
<xsl:variable name="total" select="
  sum(song[Stop_Time &gt; 0]/Stop_Time | song[not(Stop_Time &gt; 0)]/Total_Time)
  -
  sum(song/Start_Time)
" />
```

For your XML sample this evaluates to `583274`, i.e. `9m, 43s`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will try it and get back to you. I have seen this before, that you have to do the calculations twice! So is the final answer that you can't do operations on calculated columns in XSL? You have to repeat the calculations? This seems to defy the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: @Vijay: That is what it comes down to in vanilla XSLT 1.0. The `node-set()` extension function many XSLT processors implement allows you to re-use calculated results, but it's not available everywhere.

Comment: Your solution works!! I just had to figure out the place to position the code and modify the xpath a bit. I have edited your answer to show the actual code I used.

Comment: @Vijay Sorry, I've rejected the edit. You can put the code you've ended up using into your own post, but it would not have been a relevant addition to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath function [sum](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) and select with the expression all the nodes to sum.
For example

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/my/node)"/>
```

Comment: The duration column is not a node in the original XML file, so cannot parse it, I think. Does XSL allow selecting nodes in the document it's generating? I tried what you said, and this is the advice I found while researching as well, but no luck with it.

Comment: If the duration is always `stop - start` why dont't you sum all stop time and then subtract the sum of all start time?

Comment: since `start` and `stop` are optional, the actual formula is `(stop | total) - (start | 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="totalduration" select="
  sum($songs/song[Stop_Time > 0]/Stop_Time | $songs/song[not(Stop_Time > 0)]/Total_Time )
  -
  sum($songs/song/Start_Time)
" />
<p> Total Duration for playlist:   
  <xsl:call-template name="formatTime">
    <xsl:with-param name="t" select="$totalduration"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</p>
```

This is the final code I ended up using thanks to @tomalak. I've put it here for future reference.